# Blazor app is not loading after deployed to iis server

Tags: c#, iis, blazor

I have deployed my app to a IIS server and am getting the following error when the page tries to load

I get a This page isn’t working websiteis currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

these are the errors I get in the web console on the server:
Error 1:

```
Category: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware

EventId: 1

SpanId: 12f6fabbd939776b

TraceId: dc6a807e12054525cd255c7011d0b709

ParentId: 0000000000000000

RequestId: 80000061-0001-fc00-b63f-84710c7967bb

RequestPath: /surplus

An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.

Exception:

System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.

at System.Uri.CreateThis(String uri, Boolean dontEscape, UriKind uriKind, UriCreationOptions& creationOptions)

at System.Uri..ctor(String uriString)

at Microsoft.Identity.Web.AuthorityHelpers.BuildAuthority(MicrosoftIdentityOptions options)

at Microsoft.Identity.Web.MicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthenticationBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.b__3(OpenIdConnectOptions options, IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IOptionsMonitor1 mergedOptionsMonitor, IOptionsMonitor1 msIdOptionsMonitor, IOptions`1 msIdOptions)

at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigureNamedOptions`5.Configure(String , TOptions )

at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsFactory`1.Create(String )

at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsMonitor`1.<>c__DisplayClass10_0.b__0()

at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode )

at System.Lazy`1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper , Boolean )

at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()

at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()

at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsCache1.GetOrAdd(String , Func1 )

at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsMonitor`1.Get(String )

at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.InitializeAsync(AuthenticationScheme scheme, HttpContext context)

at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandlerProvider.GetHandlerAsync(HttpContext context, String authenticationScheme)

at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.g__Awaited|6_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddleware middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)

Error 2:

Category: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware

EventId: 3

SpanId: 12f6fabbd939776b

TraceId: dc6a807e12054525cd255c7011d0b709

ParentId: 0000000000000000

RequestId: 80000061-0001-fc00-b63f-84710c7967bb

RequestPath: /surplus

An exception was thrown attempting to execute the error handler.

Exception:

System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.

at System.Uri.CreateThis(String uri, Boolean dontEscape, UriKind uriKind, UriCreationOptions& creationOptions)

at System.Uri..ctor(String uriString)

at Microsoft.Identity.Web.AuthorityHelpers.BuildAuthority(MicrosoftIdentityOptions options)

at Microsoft.Identity.Web.MicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthenticationBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.b__3(OpenIdConnectOptions options, IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IOptionsMonitor1 mergedOptionsMonitor, IOptionsMonitor1 msIdOptionsMonitor, IOptions`1 msIdOptions)

at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigureNamedOptions`5.Configure(String , TOptions )

at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsFactory`1.Create(String )

at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsMonitor`1.<>c__DisplayClass10_0.b__0()

at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode )

--- End of stack trace from previous location ---

at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()

at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()

at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsCache1.GetOrAdd(String , Func1 )

at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsMonitor`1.Get(String )

at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.InitializeAsync(AuthenticationScheme scheme, HttpContext context)

at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandlerProvider.GetHandlerAsync(HttpContext context, String authenticationScheme)

at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.HandleException(HttpContext context, ExceptionDispatchInfo edi)

Error 3:

Category: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpServer

EventId: 2

SpanId: 12f6fabbd939776b

TraceId: dc6a807e12054525cd255c7011d0b709

ParentId: 0000000000000000

RequestId: 80000061-0001-fc00-b63f-84710c7967bb

RequestPath: /surplus

Connection ID "18158513703463419998", Request ID "80000061-0001-fc00-b63f-84710c7967bb": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.

Exception:

System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.

at System.Uri.CreateThis(String uri, Boolean dontEscape, UriKind uriKind, UriCreationOptions& creationOptions)

at System.Uri..ctor(String uriString)

at Microsoft.Identity.Web.AuthorityHelpers.BuildAuthority(MicrosoftIdentityOptions options)

at Microsoft.Identity.Web.MicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthenticationBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.b__3(OpenIdConnectOptions options, IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IOptionsMonitor1 mergedOptionsMonitor, IOptionsMonitor1 msIdOptionsMonitor, IOptions`1 msIdOptions)

at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigureNamedOptions`5.Configure(String , TOptions )

at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsFactory`1.Create(String )

at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsMonitor`1.<>c__DisplayClass10_0.b__0()

at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode )

at System.Lazy`1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper , Boolean )

at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()

at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()

at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsCache1.GetOrAdd(String , Func1 )

at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsMonitor`1.Get(String )

at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.InitializeAsync(AuthenticationScheme scheme, HttpContext context)

at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandlerProvider.GetHandlerAsync(HttpContext context, String authenticationScheme)

at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.g__Awaited|6_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddleware middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)

at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.HandleException(HttpContext context, ExceptionDispatchInfo edi)

at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.g__Awaited|6_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddleware middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)

at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContextOfT`1.ProcessRequestAsync()
```

any help would be amazing!

thanks  :)

Answer (score 0):

`System.UriFormatException with Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined` message is one of the errors that is almost always related to code.

**Root cause:**

If the input value is not what the application expected, this exception is generated. In other words, the application was expecting a valid URI but the value it received wasn’t in URI format.

**Solution:**

This issue may occur because of user behavior (the value submitted into the function). No matter what the root cause is, the application should catch the exception. Implement try-catch block in that function to handle this exception.

It also helps finding the assembly that is throwing the error (look at stack trace for this information). If it’s a third-party component, you will need to contact them. They might already have a fix or updated assembly.

You can also try to figure out how that value is passed to that function. Review the inputs and use-cases. Ask your user about the steps to reproduce it.  It could be because of a user who enters invalid information in a form. However, no matter what the input is, the application should catch the exception.

**Sourced from**：

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/system-uriformatexception/ba-p/984827